# To "offer one's hand" and "take one's hand" is there a single word or phrase replacement?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a question regarding the usage of these two terms together. It sounds repetitive to me in this example:

Sample sentence:

> He floated gracefully across the room, *offered his hand* and whispered, “Come, child.”
> *She took his hand*; her lip quivered.

Is there another phrase or word I can use in place of one of these phrases?

I've thought about what to change and I come back to these two phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you move things around a bit and use the relative pronoun ***which***:

> He floated gracefully across the room and whispered, “Come, child,” offering his hand *(to her)*, ***which*** she took *(hold of)*, *as* her lip quivered.

*She took his hand* sounds alright, but *she took it* stops a bit short. The parentheses are optional, but the sentence reads better if you use them.

Comment: Oh thank you.. That does sound better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That single word would be "it."

Example:

> He floated gracefully across the room, offered his hand and whispered,
> "Come, child."
>
> Her lip quivering, she took it.

Notice I changed the second sentence. The one that appears in your example smacks of a writer ham-fistedly trying to appear clever by using a semicolon but only making the phrasing clunky instead.

Comment: I try to avoid "it" if I can. Thanks for the tip on the semicolon. I am still learning English grammar and confused on comma splices.

Comment: Why would you try to avoid "it" if you can? That's not anything writing coaches, editors, grammarians, English teachers, or anyone I know of suggests or recommends. To the contrary, if you can aptly use "it," you should since it's more succinct.

Comment: I try to avoid it when possible because when I use it too often it sounds redundant. Also I feel like there is a time and a place for it. I tend to use a descriptive word in its place if able. Haha, I just drove myself nuts there. I might be OCD.